# Corresponding Rational Function

Tags: complex-analysis

I know that all meromorphic functions on $\mathbb{CP}^1$ are rational functions. However, I'm having some troubles understanding how to obtain the corresponding rational function from a meromorphic one.

For example, given an invertible matrix $A = \begin{bmatrix}a, b\\c, d\end{bmatrix} \in GL_2(\mathbb{C})$ we define $F_A : \mathbb{CP}^1 \to \mathbb{CP}^1$ by
$$F_A([z:w]):=[az+bw:cz+dw]$$
 What is the rational function corresponding to $F_A$? Probably it's a very easy computation but I don't get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that
$$\mathbb{C} = \{[z:1]\,|\,z\in \mathbb{C}\}\subseteq \mathbb{CP}^1$$
Hence you can identify $F_A$ with a rational function $f_A$ given by
$$f_A(z) = F_A([z:1])$$
Then
$$f_A(z) = \frac{az + b}{cz + d}$$